# Sorting JSON data by keys value

Tags: python, json, list, discogs-api

I am currently getting JSON data from the discogs API (mp3 tag data) and wish to sort the results by the key's value. In this case I am trying to get data for a Guns n Roses song and the output has 1988 as the first one while the data actually has a record from 1987. How can I sort this data so that I can get to the sorted data by year (olderst to newest). The code below sorts by either key or value but thats not what I intended to get. Please help.

```
import json
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?sort=year&sort_order=asc&artist=%22Guns+N%27+Roses%22&track=%22Sweet+Child+O%27+Mine%22&format_exact=Album&type=master')
request.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')
request.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
json_raw= response.readlines()
json_object = json.loads(json_raw[0])



for row in json_object['results']:
    try:
        from operator import itemgetter
        for k, v in sorted(row.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
            print k, v
    except KeyError: 
        pass
```

Comment: I'd help if you included a sample of the JSON data..

Comment: By the looks of it, you are using [this API](http://www.discogs.com/developers/resources/database/search-endpoint.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use list-comprehension and `sorted()` function for this:

```
# filter  json_object['results']  first, as some of the items are missing the key 'year'

In [33]: results = [x for x in json_object['results'] if 'year' in x]

In [34]: sorted(results, key=lambda x: x['year'])
```

**or :**

```
In [79]: from operator import itemgetter

In [80]: sorted(results, key=itemgetter('year'))
```

Comment: Than you, this works like a charm, as you can tell, I am a newbie and have a long way to go..

Answer (score 1):

To sort a list of dictionaries, use a `methodcaller` with the key on which to sort; you want to sort the *results* list, not the contained dictionaries. Moreover, some of the entries do not *have* a year, and that could lead to errors:

```
from operator import methodcaller

for row in sorted(json_object['results'], key=methodcaller('get', 'year', None)):
    # process the row dictionary
```

The `methodcaller` definition will basically do a `entry.get('year', None)` for each entry in `json_object['results']`, giving the `sorted` method the value to sort on.

You should *not* use `readlines()` to read your JSON response, it'll mis-interpret newlines. Let the `json` library do the reading instead (note the `.load()`, no `s` at the end):

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
json_object = json.load(response)
```

Comment: I am new to this forum and I am unable to post the JSON as it says I have few characters left to post...

Comment: Take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for more help.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but when I run this now, I get an error:

Comment: C:\Python27>python test2.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
  for row in sorted(json_object['results'], key=itemgetter('year')):
 KeyError: 'year'

Comment: @PremMinister: I tested the code some more, and made an update. I switched techniques a little, actually.